# How to pass a variable to a function which has already implement non-standard evaluation in its argument in R?

Tags: r, function, non-standard-evaluation

I am trying to wrap up a function from an R package. From the source codes, it appears that it has non-standard evaluations for some arguments. How can I write my function to pass the value to the argument that has non-standard evaluation implemented?

#### Here is a toy example

```
data <- data.frame(name = 1:10)
#Suppose the one below is the function from that package
toy.fun <- function(dat, var) {
    eval(substitute(var), dat)
}
> toy.fun(data, name)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

#### Here is what I try to wrap it

```
toy.fun2 <- function(dat, var2) {
    var_name <- deparse(substitute(var2))
    #example, but for similar purpose. 
    data_subset <- dat[var_name] 
    toy.fun(data_subset, var2)
}
> toy.fun2(data, name)
 Error in eval(substitute(var), dat) : object 'var2' not found
```

#### Edit

I should make the question more clear, in which I want to pass different variable name to the function argument in the wrapper for `var2`. So that when there are different variable names in the data, it could use that name for both data selection, and pass to the function I try to wrap. The source codes for `exceedance` function from `heatwaveR` has this  `ts_y <- eval(substitute(y), data)` to capture the input variable `y` already. This is equivalent to my `toy.fun`.

I have modified the `toy.fun2` for clarity.

#### Edit 2

It turns out the solution is quite easy, just by substituting the entire function including arguments, and evaluating it.

```
toy.fun2 <- function(dat, var2) {
  var_name <- deparse(substitute(var2))
  #example, but for similar purpose.
  data_subset <- dat[var_name]
  exprs <- substitute(toy.fun(data_subset, var2))
  eval(exprs, parent.frame()) 
  #include `envir` argument if this is to be worked in data.table
}
```

Comment: Non-standard evaluation is non-standard. What works for `toy.fun` is not necessarily going to work for some other non-standard evaluation.  You should specify which function you're trying to wrap.

Comment: For example, @DonaldSeinen's answer below works fine for your example, but might not work in tidyverse-style NSE, which doesn't fully support dots arguments.  E.g. see https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/231 .

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for the suggestion. I have modified the question, and hope it provides more clarity this time.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the call using `match.call`, replace the function name and evaluate it.
It would also be possible to modify the other arguments as needed. Look at the source of `lm` to see another example of this approach.

```
toy.fun2 <- function(dat, var) {
  cl <- match.call()
  cl[[1L]] <- quote(toy.fun)
  eval.parent(cl)
}
toy.fun2(data, name)
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

### Added

The question was revised after this answer was already posted.  This addresses the new question.  The line setting cl[[2]] could alternately  be written as   `cl[[2]] <- dat[deparse(cl[[3]])]` .

```
toy.fun2 <- function(dat, var2) {
  cl <- match.call()
  cl[[1]] <- quote(toy.fun)
  cl[[2]] <- dat[deparse(substitute(var2))]
  names(cl)[3] <- "var"
  eval.parent(cl)
}
toy.fun2(data, name)
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: It's not exactly the answer for my actual problem, but did give me an idea. I could `substitute` the entire `toy.fun` function call, and the variables inside will automatically be substituted. Evaluating that expression will give me the result.

Comment: The eval.parent(substitute(...)) paradigm basically defines a macro and an interface is given by the defmacro function in the gtools package.