# Build function before passing it to other functions

Tags: r, function, parameters, ellipsis

My goal is to take additional arguments passed through the ellipsis `...` (see `?dots` for more info) and build a new generic function with the parameters already set and pass this to another function.

For example, given the two functions:

```r
foo <- function(v, FUN, ...) {
    ## code here to build NEWFUN
    SomeFun(v, NEWFUN)
}

bar <- function(v, FUN) {
    SomeFun(v, FUN)
}
```

I would like to be able to do this in `foo`:

```r
bar(x, FUN = \(x) paste(x, collapse = ", "))
```

By calling `foo(x, paste, collapse = ", ")`.

### My Attempt

We start with a simple function takes a base `R` function (here `paste`) and applys it to a vector. Note, I'm trying to make this as simple as possible, so I have removed sanity checks. Also, I wrote this to be demonstrated only with the base `R` function `paste`.

```r
FunAssign <- function(f, x) f(x)
```

And here is my naive attempt:

```r
foo <- function(v, FUN, ...) {
    FUN <- \(x) FUN(x, ...)
    FunAssign(FUN, v)
}
```

And calling it, we get the error:

```r
foo(letters[1:5], paste, collapse = ", ")
#> Error in FUN(x, ...) : unused argument (collapse = ", ")
```

As explained above, the desired output when calling `foo(letters[1:5], paste, collapse = ", ")` can be emulated by calling `bar` like so:

```r
bar <- function(v, FUN) FunAssign(FUN, v)

bar(letters[1:5], FUN = \(x) paste(x, collapse = ", "))
#> [1] "a, b, c, d, e"
```

I thought my attempt with `foo` would work because if we do something like the below it appears that we are on the right track:

```r
baz <- function(FUN, ...) \(x) FUN(x, ...)

baz(paste, collapse = ", ")(letters[1:5])
#> [1] "a, b, c, d, e"
```

I have found several resources that almost get at what I'm after, but nothing that quite hits the spot.

- [R: using a list for ellipsis arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3142731/4408538). This one is good, however `do.call` evaluates the expression.
- And then there is [How to create an R function programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12982528/4408538). But again, this looks like it is evaluating the function and thus returning a value.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but a couple of [non-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143425/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-function-which-has-already-implement-non-standard-ev) or [ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77466226/pass-custom-function-with-arguments-to-r-terra-roll-function)

Comment: I don't see the relevance of having FunAssign written in C++.  You should get it to work the way you want (and that's not clear to me) with FunAssign written in R, then translate it to C++ if necessary.

Comment: @user2554330, thanks for your comments. I've updated my question and eliminated the additional complications around compiled code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your first idea would work if you didn't overwrite the `FUN` variable in `foo()`.  That is, this works for me:

```
FunAssign <- function(f, x) f(x)

foo <- function(v, FUN, ...) {
    force(FUN)
    FUN2 <- \(x) FUN(x, ...)
    FunAssign(FUN2, v)
}

foo(letters[1:5], paste, collapse = ", ")
```

Besides renaming the second `FUN` in `foo()`, I added the `force(FUN)` command.  This is not necessary in this example, but generally speaking it's a good idea to make sure arguments that are needed in a created function are evaluated.  I think that automatically happens in this code (since `FunAssign` will use it), but I'm superstitious about things like that.

Edited to add: the explanation for this is fairly simple.

- The variable `FUN` in the function `FUN2()` is not evaluated until `FUN2()` is called.
- When `FUN2` is called within `FunAssign(FUN2, v)`, R tries to evaluate `FUN(x, ...)`.
- Since `FUN` is not defined in that function, R looks in the parent environment, and finds `FUN` in the evaluation frame of `foo()` as an argument to the function call.
- In your original code where you had both objects named `FUN`, that lookup happened after you had overwritten the argument with a different variable (the function I called `FUN2`).
- When R tries to evaluate `FUN(x, ...)`, in your code the `FUN` it is working with is the one that was defined right there, and R attempts a recursive call, but gives an error because that function only has one argument named `x`.

The key thing here is that the body of a function is just an unevaluated expression.  It doesn't get evaluated until you call the function, and that's when R tries to find all the objects it uses, including the functions it calls.

Comment: This is great. I wonder why this works? I suspect it has to do with environments and scoping. I need to read more for sure.

Comment: I've added more explanation.